# How to change background color of numbers in ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html

Using Javascript, I would like change the background color of the numbers in an ordered HTML list. The background color of the list content should not change.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the following article : [**Style Ordered List with CSS**](https://codeasily.com/), if you have some HTML code like this :

```
<ol id="list">
  <li>
    <p>this is some text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>and some other text</p>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Then, using a CSS that looks like this :

```
ol {
  background: red;
}
li {
  background: white;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Might get you something like what you're asking for : here's the result I get *(only tested with Firefox)* :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/screenshot-question-2650667.png))</sub>

*(There are more explanations on the article I linked to at the beginning of my answer)*

**EDIT after the comment :** ooops, didn't see that part ; sorry :-(

Now that you have an ordered list, with a specific color as background for the numbers, you can plug-in some Javascript code, to change that color.

Considering that the `<ol>` tag I used here as `id="list"`, you can change its background-color with the following portion of JS code :

```
document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
```

After this is executed, you'll get something that looks like the following :

[image]
<sub>(source: [pascal-martin.fr](http://extern.pascal-martin.fr/so/screenshot-question-2650667-2.png))</sub>

Comment: @misha : ooops, sorry, I missed that part of the question :-( ;;; I've edited my answer to add some informations about that.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions for `ol` and `ul` using HTML and CSS only.

Solution for `ul`

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li::before {
  content: "• ";
  background-color: red;
}

<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ul>
```

Solution for `ol` using [counter-increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    counter-reset: my-counter;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: my-counter;
}

ol li::before {
  content: counter(my-counter) ". ";
  background-color: red;
}

<ol>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is good. but you can create it other way...

```
<!--HTML-->

<ol class="questions">
       <li><a href="#">What is your biggest fear about marriage?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">If your friends were asked to describe you in one word what would ...</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Are you closer to your family or your friends and why?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">What is the role of a wife?</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">What is the role of a husband?</a></li>
</ol>


/*==============CSS===========*/
.questions li{ 
    list-style-position:inside; 
    margin-top:1px;
    padding:0px 5px;
    background:#e7e2da;
}
.questions li a{
    padding:10px;
    display:block;  
}
```